# setTimeout runs only once then not working

Tags: javascript, html

I got `JS` as below. I want all `bootstrap` `alerts` to dissaper after 1 sec. It works just `one time` but when i add more alerts they stays as they are. What is the cause of that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function flashh(message, category) {
    if (category == "error") {
      var icon = "icon-exclamation-sign";
      category = "danger";
    } else if (category == "success") var icon = "icon-ok-sign";
    else var icon = "icon-info-sign";
    $(
      '<div class="alert alert-' +
        category +
        '"><i class="' +
        icon +
        '"></i>&nbsp;<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>' +
        message +
        "</div>"
    ).prependTo("#putFlashMsg");
  }
});
```

**setTimeout:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $(".alert")
      .fadeTo(1000, 0)
      .slideUp(1000, function () {
        $(this).remove();
      });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `setTimeout` is only called once. If you want to have multiple calls, use `setInterval`, that is used exactly the same way but is called until `clearInterval` stops it.

Comment: You mean `clearInterval` ;-)

Comment: can u exactly show what and where should i implement based on my code?

Comment: Replace your `setTimeout` by a `setInterval` and leave the rest as is.

Comment: thx, that solve my issue. I marked this as answer. Can u simply check my other post?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433262/datatable-js-one-of-the-columns-id-values-are-empty

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout only runs once, what you are looking for is setInterval which runs until stopped every n seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $(".alert")
          .fadeTo(1000, 0)
          .slideUp(1000, function () {
              $(this).remove();
         });
     }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: that doesn;t work i took your code and now none alerts dissapers

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add an alert you should also create a new `setTimeout`; `setTimeout` should be in the "flashh" function.

```js
function flashh(message, category) {
    if (category == "error") {
      var icon = "icon-exclamation-sign";
      category = "danger";
    } else if (category == "success") var icon = "icon-ok-sign";
    else var icon = "icon-info-sign";
    var alert = $(
      '<div class="alert alert-' +
        category +
        '"><i class="' +
        icon +
        '"></i>&nbsp;<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>' +
        message +
        "</div>"
    )
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        alert
          .fadeTo(1000, 0)
          .slideUp(1000, function () {
              $(this).remove();
         });
    }, 5000);
    alert.prependTo("#putFlashMsg");
  }
```

Comment: i think there is a typo as once after i've implemented your solution none alerts are even shown

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No. Just after your implementation i do not see even my alerts